# Is this site going to die?

Tags: discussion

With the fail of Windows Phone in general, won't this site follow in it's footsteps?

Unless, that is, this site also has information on *hacking* Windows Phones. Then it will likely stay.

Comment: Why do you say that Windows Phone has failed? Sure, it might have a relatively small market share, but that doesn't mean that people aren't still choosing them over other brands?

Comment: @RowlandShaw I don't see that.

Comment: Note that market share is not the same as usage share. In other words, the number of people *using* Windows phones is certainly much greater than the number of people *buying* Windows phones in the latest quarter, which is what the media is reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phones usage share and market shares have decreased. But that does not mean it is dead.

**Why Windows Mobile isn't dead?**

- My Windows 10 Mobile gets update almost every month.
- The mobile OS development is almost on par with the PC version.
- Core apps and services are still being activetly developed on Windows 10.
- With convergence, there is not much work for Microsoft to keep Windows Mobile alive.

**Why this site should continue?**

- For the people who still use Windows 10 Mobile. This may be a small community but it is still large enough to run a website for.
- For those who use Windows mobile in form factors other than phone. I have seen tablets, stick PC's and even very low cost laptops with Windows 10 Mobile OS.
- And above all for the reason that, "Future is yet to be written".

Answer (score 1):

Not at all. It's true that windows phones have low market share but its noticeable that low-end (i.e low priced) Windows phones are more popular therefore the devices are large in no. in-spite of having low market shares. Market shares actually decline when Microsoft stopped making the phones. People are still stuck on this beautiful OS. Moreover, Microsoft is still stuck on W10M therefore it will be worth to wait till the launch of [Ultimate Mobile Device](http://www.forbes.com/sites/ewanspence/2016/11/24/microsoft-surface-phone-rumor-leak-ceo-satya-nadella/#20952d032b1b) before predicting something like that.